# Redirect unavailable pages to 404 without changing URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have an hidden folder `hidden_folder` which can be accessed by the server with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ hidden_folder/$1
```

Now, I want to redirect all unavailable pages to 404 error page content.

**Illustration 1** : When user tries to go here `http://website.com/some_unavailable_uri`, the url of the page doesn't change but the content will be the one of /error/404.php

**Illustration 2** : http://www.apple.com/test. This page does not exist, the url does not change, but the content displays error.

Basically, it should be `if file does not exist, then redirect content`.  I'd tried something but with no success.

*First try :*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond hidden_folder%{REQUEST_URI} -f   # %{REQUEST_URI} already has "/" at its beginning
RewriteRule ^.*$ error/404.php [NC,L]
```

*Second try :*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}hidden_folder%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ error/404.php [NC,L]
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Outlyer.

The actual working code is :

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the requested file is not in hidden_folder as a file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}hidden_folder%{REQUEST_URI} !-f

# AND

# If the requested file not is in hidden_folder as a folder
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}hidden_folder%{REQUEST_URI} !-d

# AND

# If the requested file is not in root as a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# AND

# If the requested file is not in root as a folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# AND

# ???    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/hidden_folder

# THEN Redirect content
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ error/404.php [L]

####################################################

# Enable the deletion of hidden_folder in urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ hidden_folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/hidden_folder`: this one means "if the requested path doesn't start with `/hidden_folder`"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need a simple `ErrorDocument` with use of `http://` in target since that causes URL to change in the browser.

Use this line top of your .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
```

And don't forget to comment out your rewrite rules doing same.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions are tested also on redirects, so you must make sure that the 404 redirect doesn't catch more than it should.
What this means is that `%{REQUEST_URI}` will contain `hidden_folder` once it's been redirected, so you must add a `RewriteCond` to avoid it.

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/hidden_folder%{REQUEST_URI} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/hidden_folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ error/404.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ hidden_folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: As a sidenote, since you aren't relying on `ErrorDocument`, your `404.php` should send the 404 HTTP header.

Comment: You didn't mention any requirement about this, but it's also worth noting that with this solution you can still access the files using `hidden_folder` in the URL